# Is it bad practice for a composited instance to reference its parent? If yes, why?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript

I'm building a `Selection` class that holds and allows manipulating selected `Items` on a canvas.

- The `Selection` is part of the `Document`, the top-level app-container if you will.
- I'd like to be able to clear the selection from inside the `Selection` class.
- The problem is that selection creation/clearing is done on the `Document`.

Is it a code smell to inject the parent `Document` in the child `Selection` so I can invoke its methods from within `Selection`?

If yes, why and what are alternatives to this?

```
class Document {
  constructor() {
    this.currentSelection = null
  }

  createSelection(items) { 
    // here I'm creating a Selection and injecting
    // this `Document` within it.
    this.currentSelection = new Selection(items, this)
  }

  clearSelection() {
    this.currentSelection = null
  }
}


class Selection extends HTMLElement {
  // this class also renders the flyout buttons that follow around
  // the selection on the canvas. The buttons can call methods on
  // this class.
  constructor(items, document) {
    this.items = items
    this.document = document
  }

  updateFillColor(fillColor) {
    // updates all this.items fill color, just a placeholder for now
  }

  clear() {
    this.document.clearSelection()
  }
}
```

**Note**: The above is just an example. My actual problem is significantly more complicated (involves calling more methods on the parent), but is conceptually the same.

Comment: Could you clarify why you'd want to command a `Document` object from or via a `Selection` object? In your example there's a call to non existing method `document.clearSelection()`. That's slightly confusing. Should it be `document.cancelSelection()` instead?

Comment: @COMEFROM Yes, my bad. Let me edit the code.

Comment: Ask yourself: who cleans your room? you or the dirt?

Comment: @ThomasJunk My example might have been a bit bad. That doesn't mean there is no case where I would have to do this type of child -> parent communication. I'd like to know of ways to handle that.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides To rephrase my hint: it is a question about `responsibility`. As long as your problem is abstract, the answer is: it depends. If it is concrete, you may decide for yourself.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Perhaps my question was posed a bit confusingly; What I meant to ask is, is this is a valid child->parent communication technique? If it has problems, what are those problems and what are the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You ask "Is it a code smell to inject the parent `Document` in the child `Selection` so I can invoke it's methods from within `Selection`?"

This could smell of needless coupling of the two classes, but surely there are parent-child relationships where it is sensible to pass the parent to the child object.

One question you should ask yourself is: why does the `Selection` need to know about or depend on `Document`? If `Document` is complex and contains methods that are of no relevance to `Selection` this begins to smell.

If the `Selection` only needed to let `Document` know that it has been cleared, all the selection would need is a reference to a `SelectionClearedListener` with the `clearSelection` method, which the `Document` class would implement and that gets called from the `clear` method on `Selection`. Thus, you could pass along the document to the selection without it knowing that it's a `Document`. The point is what role the document plays to the selection; in this case, someone that acts on clearing the selection.

You write that your actual problem is significantly more complicated and that the `Selection` needs to call more methods on the parent `Document`. You can follow the reasoning: what other objects does the `Selection` need to interact with that may actually be a `Document`, but which the `Selection` does not care to know is a `Document`? Those could be known to the `Selection` as other types of object and be passed to the `Selection` as separate objects. (In fact, those other objects might be implemented by different classes than `Document`. Dividing the responsibilities of `Document` into separate objects may reduce complexity.)

A relevant principle that captures the above is the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), which can be applied to your example: "`Selection` should not be forced to depend on methods of `Document` it does not use".

In your real scenario, does the `Document` contain methods that `Selection` does not need to depend on? If so, this dependency between the two objects starts to smell.

Another consideration is that Selection may be reused for other collections of items. Again we may ask what role does the object have for the child.

Comment: What you are saying in the 1st paragraph is basically: 'If you want to communicate from a child to a parent, use events instead'? Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: No, that is not the point I am trying to make. You could call any method on Document to perform operations etc. The point is if the parent or owner plays the role of Document to the Selection or whether its not relevant to the Selection that it is a Document.

Comment: It's not. The child simply wants to call actions on the Document. It doesn't care if it's a Document.

Comment: I have added to my answer. Basically I think you cannot generalize about injecting parent object to the child being a code smell.